# Windows 10 Mobile Background Low Quality

Tags: windows-10-mobile, settings, nokia-lumia-535, lock-screen

I have a Lumia 535 running Windows 10 Mobile (latest build), screen resolution 540 x 960.

The problem that I was trying to solve, is to make the picture look good on my phone. I've tweaked for some time, still no changes. I even downloaded a 4k image.

My Lock Screen looks good. I even rotated the images:
[image: lock]

My Start looks so lame:

[image: start]

Somehow image with dimension 1024 x 1170, is quite considerable.

**Is there a way we can solve this?** The square where you make crop the image, produce this "zoomed", low quality image - in Start but not in Lock Screen.

Note: I just went to Settings - Extras - Color Profile and scale the color saturation and temperature. Still nothing happens, I didn't see any changes.

Comment: Can you post screenshots of both lockscreen and start using same picture

Comment: You can try stock-Rom,,,,after your picture will be clear..so u can try it..

Comment: @userRR Can you elaborate a little? What do you mean by "stock-ROM"?

Answer (score 2):

I have dual SIM variant of 535 and my start and lockscreen have almost identical apperance.
[image]
[image]
 I usually used to download the desktop baackgrounds from my PC and then have them on my phone to set. You may try this work around.

Comment: I tried this one already, all image (HD / Ultra). I used my laptop by downloading the images, due to `microsoft edge` it's like it down sampling the image. Yes, this apply for identical lockscreen and start. But I don't want it that way. The image that I used for my start is a 4k image.  :(

Comment: What the way you want it? Different pics and better quality for start?